# "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" when connecting WEB API to client-side

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, windows-forms-designer

**Client side: Windows Form / Server side: WEB API_ASP. NET Core 6**

When the client-side and the server-side are in the same computer, it can operate correctly, but when the client-side and the server-side are in the different computer, it will show this error in the client side:"ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED".

I also use postman to test the connection, and the result is the same.
(Postman is in the same computer as client-side)
[Test in Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYtfj.png)

---

## The solutions & details I have tried or verified:

1. Close the firewall
2. Complete the HTTPS certification in server-side
3. [Set the CORS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHF43.png)
   (I temporarily set it to allow requests from any origin)
   (allowanyOrigins should only be done to test it.)
4. [Set the logger in server-side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MigjR.png)
   (But I didn't receive any error message when I tried to connect)
5. The apiURL I use in client-side is: "https://140.124.45.39:7214/api/Email"
   140.124.45.39 is the computer IP of server-side.

BTW, I'm not using proxy in my network setting.

## The potential problem in my opinion:

I'm using my school's network, I'm not sure whether this makes influences or not.

---

I have attached all relevant code below.
Thank you for reading my question, I'll be very appreciate if anybody can solve this problem.

### Code in client-side

```
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace Practice_UI
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        async Task<bool> SendEmailToApi(string email)    //將 Email 傳給 API
        {
            try
            {
                
                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())    
                {
                                                                                   
                    var json = new
                    {
                        email
                    };

                    string jsonEmail = JsonSerializer.Serialize(json);  

                    var content = new StringContent(jsonEmail, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                    string apiUrl = "https://140.124.45.39:7214/api/Email"; 

                    
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(apiUrl, content);

                    
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        
                        string statusCode = response.StatusCode.ToString();
                        MessageBox.Show($"API請求失敗，狀態碼：{statusCode}", "API Request Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        return false;

                    }
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"錯誤：{ex.Message}", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return false;
            }
        }

        private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string email = txtEmail.Text;

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email))
            {
                bool success = await SendEmailToApi(email);
                if (success)
                {
                    lblStatus.Text = "Email sent successfully!";
                    lblStatus.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                }
                else
                {
                    lblStatus.Text = "Failed to send email.";
                    lblStatus.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                lblStatus.Text = "Please enter a valid email.";
                lblStatus.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Code in server-side

**Controller**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;


namespace PracticeAPI2
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class EmailController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<EmailController> _logger;
        public EmailController(ILogger<EmailController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> SendEmail([FromBody] EmailRequest request)  
        {
            try
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("Received a POST request.");

                
                await Task.Delay(100); // Simulate some asynchronous processing
                string email = request.Email;
                return Ok(new { Success = true, Message = "Email received and processed successfully." });  
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Catch and log the exception
                _logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while processing the email.");

                // Return an error response
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, new { Success = false, Message = "An error occurred while processing the email." });
            }

        }

    }
}
```

**program.cs**

```
var MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

// 紀錄提供者
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Host.ConfigureLogging(logging =>
{
    logging.ClearProviders();
    logging.AddConsole();
    logging.AddDebug();
    logging.AddEventSourceLogger();
});

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();


// Add Cores
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                      policy =>
                      {
                          policy.WithOrigins("https://140.124.45.140")  //140.124.45.140 is client-side's IP
                                              .AllowAnyOrigin()
                                              .AllowAnyHeader()
                                              .AllowAnyMethod();
                      });
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

// Add Cores
app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

//app.UseEndpoints();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Comment: If your server is behind a router, you'll need to do port forwarding.

Comment: How you host your web api inside the server? By using the IIS or Kestrel?

Comment: Did you enable CORS?